# Load and read signal into a wave generator using Python and USBTMC in Linux?

Tags: python, usb

I need to load the signal shown into a wave generator.

Code to drive wave generator via USBTMC:

I have used the following to create sample code.

How do I load the created chirp signal into the wavegenerator?

Answer (score 1):

*USBTMC* is *USB test & measurement class*. The commands are SCPI commands. The driver system driver that has to be loaded is `usb_tmc` (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/class/usbtmc.c). Check this in the output of `dmesg` after plugging in the Agilent device. The wavefrom generator should then appear in `/dev/usbtmcx` or `/dev/ttySx` (replace the x with number on your system)

> Configuring interface
>
> Recent Linux kernels support USBTMC out of the box. Connect your
>   instrument and check if `/dev/usbtmc*` exists. Set appropriate
>   permissions to `/dev/usbtmc*`
>
> Open an interface to the USB instrument `t0 = usbtmc('/dev/usbtmc0')`
>
> Write to listener: `usbtmc_write(t0, '*IDN?')`
>
> Blocking read call [binary read], returns `uint8 array data = usbtmc_read(t0, 10000)`
>    Convert uint8 array to string, char(data)
>
> close usbtmc session `usbtmc_close(t0)`

http://wiki.octave.org/Instrument_control_package (is not Python; is [Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave), only to show basic usage).

In Python it is similar. See http://scruss.com/blog/tag/usbtmc/.

First check `dmesg` that driver `usb_tmc` is loaded when you plug the Agilent device in and follow the instructions on https://github.com/python-ivi/python-usbtmc (create udev rule,..., check if /dev/usbtmc0 appears, etc.)

If all is OK, write a simple test script to see if the Agilent device responds:

```
import usbtmc
instr =  usbtmc.Instrument(2391, 5973) // The 2391 and 5973 are USB idVendor and idProduct of the Agilent MSO7104A converted to decimal
print(instr.ask("\***IDN?"))
# returns 'AGILENT TECHNOLOGIES,MSO7104A,MY********,06.16.0001'
```

Then you write a Python 'driver' that maps the standard TMC commands to Python functions (`read()`, `write()`,...) like `usbtmc.py`  in https://gist.github.com/pklaus/2597049. You have this in [here](http://paste2.org/7Yf22D4C).

A very rudimentary waveform-generator control script is in http://markjones112358.co.nz/projects/Python-Controlled-Function-Generator/

If you want to set a *frequency*, you write the SCPI command `FREQ` followed by the desired value:

```
freq = 1000
write("FREQ %f" % freq)
```

If you want to set an *amplitude*, you write the command `VOLT` followed by the desired value:

```
amplitude = 5
write("VOLT %f" % amplitude)
```

---

The complicated part is *creating and downloading a binary arbitrary file*.

You can not load the Agilent with the NumPy matrix directly, because it accepts only special binary files, so you have to convert the chirp matrix into a binary file. See **http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/E4400-90627.pdf** page 42, **62**. Maybe translate the example on page 62 to Python to generate the binary arb file

When you created the waveform binary arb file you can transfer it using SCPI write operations  **https://community.keysight.com/thread/20217**  (in C#)

```
  // Downloading
  oFio.WriteIEEEBlock("SOURce1:DATA:ARBitrary testarb,",z,true); binary write
```

Translated to Python when using a Python driver like above, this could be:

`binary_write("SOURce1:DATA:ARBitrary testarb,", z, true);` (binary write)

See http://rfmw.em.keysight.com/spdhelpfiles/33500/webhelp/US/Content/__I_SCPI/DATA_Subsystem.htm

(In the user guide http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/33220-90002.pdf on pages 234 ff is also a summary of the related SCPI commands. Search the Internet for '*agilent write arb*').

In https://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletter/articles/downloading-a-custom-waveform-to-an-arbitrary-waveform-generator.html is a MATLAB toolbox named *Quick-Control Function Generator in Instrument Control Toolbox* that solved this issue.